# Can i get the value of specific CSS attribute inside the element in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom

I am a beginner in coding.

I have came across scenario in react where i can set my style dynamically based on condition.

`style={{display:index > this.state.indexVal ? 'inline': 'none',}}`

Can I use above concept for the getting current elements css one attribute value and changing other based on the same?

Expecting something like this

```
 style={{display: currentElement.backgroundColor === 'red ? 'inline': 'none',}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a react way to perform checking like this and access elements directly. Since you want to "know" component state that can be changed (background color of some element in your case) - you should save it in component state (or pass to component props from parent element if you control this from parent component). Then you will be able to check this value in state or props.

You can user React Refs to access some element directly, but this is bad practice and you should do this only if you 100% can't do this with props/state:
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html